# what is PerlEx30.dll in the Perl distribution

Tags: perl, activestate

What is the use of the PerlEx30.DLL file in the ActiveState Perl Distribution?
Is it required for normal Perl scripting? 
This DLL has ActiveState copyright, hence would like to know if we need this file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a DLL for doing embedded perl in the Microsoft IIS Webserver.

http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/PerlEx/Welcome.html

However, why do you care what license the individual file has? What makes you think you can re-distribute some other part of the ActivePerl distro? (Admittedly, no research on my part)